# Find inheritance items in abstract class collection

Tags: java, class, collections, abstract

I have the following classes:

```
public class CollectionCustomClass extends ArrayList<CustomClass>
public abstract class CustomClass
public class SubClass1 extends CustomClass
public class SubClass2 extends CustomClass
```

and in a method i want to do the following:

```
CollectionCustomClass ccc = new CollectionCustomClass();
ccc.add(new SubClass1())
ccc.add(new SubClass2())
ccc.add(new SubClass1())
ccc.add(new SubClass2())

ccc.find(SubClass1)
```

The result would be the 2 Subclass1.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 ccc.find(SubClass1.class);
```

and

```
 class CollectionCustomClass<T> extends ArrayList<CustomClass>{

    public CustomClass find(Class<T> clazz) {
        for(int i=0; i< this.size(); i++)
        {
            CustomClass obj = get(i);
            if(obj.getClass() == clazz)
            {
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: [code]    public <T> CollectionCustomClass find(Class<T> clazz) {
     CollectionCustomClass answer = new CollectionCustomClass();
     for (Entity entity : this) {
      if (entity.getClass() == clazz){
       answer.add(entity);
      }
  }
        return answer;
    }
[/code]
Your answer did only return the first object, and i had to find all the objects.

Comment: ahh! you are trying to get all the items of the type SubClass1; missed that.

Comment: Yeah, can't get the format of the comment code either. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want items of the exact class, simply call `getClass` on each item and compare with the class that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can iterate through the ArrayList and do the following compare:

```
if( listName.get(i).getClass() == passedClass ){ //increase count for this class }
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList does not contain a .find(Class) method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

You would need to implement that method on CollectionCustomClass.

In pseudo-code it would be something like this:

```
public List CollectionCustomClass.find(CustomClassclazz) {
  List<CustomClass> out = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();

  // Loop through list and use instanceof to add items to out

  return out;

}
```

You could also apply generics to this method.

Answer (score 0):

you can have find method in your collection class like this

```
public int find(String className) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.size();i++) {
            if(className == this.get(i).getClass().getName()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> CollectionCustomClass find(Class<T> clazz) {
    CollectionCustomClass answer = new CollectionCustomClass();
    for (Entity entity : this) {
        if (entity.getClass() == clazz) {
            answer.add(entity);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```